# How do i get the key value from dictionary when the key is a random number?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary, nsnumber, nsuinteger

I just started learning objective-c and I'm trying to use a random number to get the value for the key of that number.

Obviously (for most of you) this won't compile since NSNumber and NSUInteger are of different data type. But this was my best shot but the compiler gives me the following error:

> Implicit conversion of a non-Objective-C pointer type 'NSUInteger *' (aka 'unsigned int *') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC

Is there anyone out there, willing to guide me to this probably trivial (for plenty of you) issue?

This is my attempt:

```
NSDictionary *refDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    @"one", [NSNumber numberWithInteger:0],
                                    @"two", [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1],
                                    @"one", [NSNumber numberWithInteger:2],
                                    @"two", [NSNumber numberWithInteger:3],
                                    @"four",[NSNumber numberWithInteger:4],
                                    @"six", [NSNumber numberWithInteger:5], nil];


        NSUInteger *dieIndex = arc4random_uniform(6);

        NSString *imageName = [refDictionary objectForKey:dieIndex];
```

Comment: NSString *imageName = [refDictionary objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:dieIndex]];

Comment: If your keys are consecutive numbers, why don't you use an array?

Comment: I get: Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSUInteger *' (aka 'unsigned int *') to parameter of type 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') @Merlevede

Comment: I wanted to learn about dictionaries :) @Sebastian

Comment: replace `numberWithInteger` with `numberWithUnsignedInteger`

Comment: `NSUInteger` is a primitive type, not an object type. Get rid of the asterisk.

Comment: And make it more flexible - don't hardcode the `6`. `NSUInteger dieIndex = arc4random_uniform(refDictionary.count);`.

Comment: The key must be an OBJECT.  NSUinteger is not an object. NSNumber is.  That's why you're able to insert the entries in the first place.

Comment: @rmaddy you will need to cast the refDictionary.count or you will get a loss of precision warning.  ((int) refDictionary.count)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

[NSNumber  **numberWithUnsignedInteger**:dieIndex]

```
 NSString *imageName = [refDictionary objectForKey: [NSNumber  numberWithUnsignedInteger:dieIndex]  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. You didn't `#import <stdlib.h>`, so the compiler doesn't know where to find the `arc4random_uniform()` function — and worse, your code implies the wrong signature for it. It returns `u_int32_t`, not `NSUInteger*`.
2. You should be using the same syntax to convert numbers to `NSNumber` that you already know how to use:

   ```
   int dieIndex = arc4random_uniform(6);

   NSString *imageName = [refDictionary objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:dieIndex]];
   ```

If you want to make your code more readable (and non-portable to older versions of iOS), you can even use new-style syntax:

```
    NSString *imageName = refDictionary[@(dieIndex)];
```

Comment: Would you not then declare it :   u_int32_t dieIndex = arc4random_uniform(6);

Comment: @markhunte You could, but those Apple typedefs are a waste of time IMHO. `int` is a perfectly reasonable container for an integer in the range 0 to 5; let's not get fancy.

Comment: Not sure I would call it getting fancy. It's just a question of why you would not use it. What would be classed as unreasonable use of the int in this case?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't use `int` to store numbers like `3.14` or `5000000000`, for example. But if you asked me "what type should I use to store values like `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, and `5`?", I would instantly answer "`int`, of course!" Hope this helps.

Comment: A kinda natural thing to do I think. What I should have asked is why you think those Apple typedefs are a waste of time. But lets not diverge these comments further. Thanks